# i need info about `contextTypes`, `propTypes` and `defaultProps` at the **OFFICIAL** *React Native* doc

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I tried to find some more info about `contextTypes`, `propTypes` and `defaultProps`  at the **OFFICIAL** *React Native*  doc but I failed, could one tell me where we can find a doc for them on **React Native** page?

At React page, it says about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops)
but if you use:

```
CustomButton.defaultProps
```

for react native, it doesn't work.

P.S. I know how to use them as I found it from other developers web-pages

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';

export default class ExampleComponent extends Component {
   static contextTypes = {
      // some context types
   };

   static propTypes = {
      prop1: PropTypes.object
   };

   static defaultProps = {
      prop1: { foobar: 'foobar' }
   };

   ...

}
```

but wonder where they got the information first,

Comment: You mean this? https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use propTypes after defining the component and then defaultProps, after describing your propTypes, like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class ExampleComponent extends Component {
   ...
}

ExampleComponent.propTypes = {
   prop1: PropTypes
}

ExampleComponent.defaultProps = {
   prop1: PropTypes
}
```

Note that using PropTypes from 'react' is deprecated and you should use PropTypes from 'prop-types'

Comment: dear i said i know them but where i can find them in react native doc